# Is it possible to Get Data from Choice Column of Sharepoint List and not from Data in Sharepoint List in Asp.Net?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, sharepoint-2010, multiple-choice

I have a List in sharepoint as 'Notifications' which has the columns 'ID,Name,Areas(MultiChoice Column)'. `I want to get Choices from 'Areas' Column and not from the DATA in Notifications List`. Is it possible. Because i want to Bind it to ASP.NET CheckBoxList Items when form Load.

Note: I am not using Microsoft.Sharepoint Namespace in ASp.Net
Help Appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can either use SPServices or SharePoint's builtin Web Services particularly the Lists service to get the schema of a particular list, which in your example is Notifications.

Calling the the GetList method of the Lists service will give you an XML schema of the list containing details of each field. From there you can just serialize or parse it to get the available list of choices from your specific column.

How to use the GetList method can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlist%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

Comment: hello @lem.mallari, i need the choice vlaues from schema of list column and not from the column containing data..please guide me?

Comment: hi Shekar, just a clarification, you want to know the values chosen per item or you want to know the values that can be chosen?

Comment: values that can be choosen! I want to bind the choice values from List that i have added while creating the list. when i add it must be dynamically added in checkbox list item too on form and vice versa. Thanks

Comment: like I said you can use GetList to get an xml schema of your current list. When you run GetList you will get an XML containing definition of each column which includes the values that can be chosen from a choice field. please try using the service as mentioned and let me know if you need any help with it and I'll be glad to reply.